# ruby kafka parse error

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka

I am trying to parse a kafka topic using Ruby.

my code :

```
require 'kafka'

kafka = Kafka.new(seed_brokers: ["someserver"])

kafka.each_message(topic: "topicname") do |message|
  puts message.offset, message.key, message.value
end
```

I am getting below error:

```
/Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/optparse.rb:1644:in `parse!': unknown keywords: seed_brokers, client_id (ArgumentError)
from /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kafka-0.0.2/lib/kafka.rb:66:in `parse'
    from /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kafka-0.0.2/lib/kafka.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from KafkaConnect.rb:4:in `new'
    from KafkaConnect.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what is the issue, I have checked the documentation and there seems to be no problem.

I have also checked using kafkacat and it is able to stream the data without no issues. challenge is with Ruby.

Comment: Which ruby kafka are you using ? documentation link please ?

Comment: Ruby 2.4.2, kafka-0.0.2

Comment: I found out it was an issue with the ruby version on mac. Once I have upgraded to ruby 2.4.1 , issue got resolved.